# Create a Dataframe of all Combinations Between Column Values (Even if No Observations)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that lists all transitions between the initial state in column x and next state in col y.

```
test = pd.DataFrame([['a','b',1],['a','c',1],['b','c',2],['d','a',1],['d','e',3]], columns = ['x','y','counts'])
```

I'm trying to create a transition matrix (dataframe) that shows the probabilities of transitioning between all the states in col x and col y. Something like this:

```
    [a ] [b]  [c]  [d]  [e]

[a] .1  .2  .3  .4  0
[b] .0  .0 .25  .75  0
[c] .0  .0  .0  .0  0
[d] .25 .25 .25  .25  0
[e]  0  0   0  0  0
```

Unfortunately, in my dataset, if there's no transitions from value 'a' to value 'b', there will be no record and any attempts to group by and unstack will give me missing values in either the rows or columns.

What I'm getting:

```
   a   b   c   e

a   0 .25 .25  0
b   0   0  1   0
d  .25  0  0  .75
```

How can I get all values of a through e on both axes?

Comment: Sorry, how do you create last dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you jezrael. I'll just add to your answer that to generate the list of missing index values in `reindex` I used the union between the column and row values.

```
##Generate the initial datafame
test = pd.DataFrame([['a','b',1],['a','c',1],['b','c',2],['d','a',1],['d','e',3]], columns = ['x','y','counts'])

## pivot to get the probabilities of the transitions.
pivot = test.groupby(['x','y'])['counts'].sum() / test2.groupby(['x'])['counts'].sum()

##unstack to get the values as a dataframe and fill with zeroes for existing transitions.
temp=pivot.unstack().fillna(0)

##fill in the missing values by reindexing on the union of values between x and y 
final=temp.reindex(index=list(set(test['x']) | set(test['y'])), columns=list(set(test['x']) | set(test['y'])), fill_value=0)
```

Comment: You can also use `temp=pivot.unstack(fill_value=0)` instead `temp=pivot.unstack().fillna(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

You need [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for fill missing values by `0` for missing categories:

```
test = test.reindex(index=list('abcde'), columns=list('abcde'), fill_value=0)
```

Also is possible `reindex` by `Multiindex` - for all unique values by [`numpy.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

```
pivot = test.groupby(['x','y'])['counts'].sum() / test.groupby(['x'])['counts'].sum()

vals = np.unique(test[['x', 'y']].values)
print (vals)
['a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e']

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([vals, vals])
final = pivot.reindex(mux, fill_value=0).unstack(fill_value=0)
print (final)
      a    b    c    d     e
a  0.00  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.00
b  0.00  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.00
c  0.00  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.00
d  0.25  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.75
e  0.00  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.00
```